# why this formula has answer in micrometer

Tags: units

Formula
e=0.8+0.06(m+0.25√d)
e=pitch error in microns
m=module in mm
d= pitch circle diameter in mm

From school we have learned that if we put value of terms like m and d (terms from above example) in millimeter in formula (C.G.S) we will get answer in millimeter and if we put value of terms like m and d (terms from above example) in meter in formula (S.I)we will get answer in meter

Then why in this formula if we are putting value of m and d in mm we are getting answer in micrometer

This there a way to indentify such diffrent formulas

Comment: I am not really sure what you are asking. But consider that both $m$ and $mm$ are dimensions of length $(1m = 1000 mm)$ and up to a factor the same thing (milli means one thousandth). I can write as an example the area of a rectangle with sides $a$ and $b$ as $A=1/1000\ a b$, where $A$ is the area in square meter, $a$ is the length in meter and $b$ is the width in millimeter.

Comment: In CGS system you should use centimeters, not millimeters. That's what the "C" stands for.

Answer (score 0):

In engineering it's not unusual to use equations where variables are put in with different units. This is usually done for convenience. It's easier to type in numbers that are of order one rather than having to correctly enter lots of zeros either side of the decimal point. There's nothing wrong with this practice as long as it's made clear what units have to be used.

In this case I'm not familiar with the equation you cite, so unless you can give us a reference to show where it comes from it's hard to make any useful comment. The dimensions seem a bit odd - for example it appears to be adding a variable with dimensions of $L$ to one with dimensions of $L^{1/2}$, though it's possible that the value of $0.25$ has dimensions rather than being a pure number.